# About using jquery mobile, best practices

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have built native applications , for iOS, Android, WP7, BB and also i have basic knowledge of web sites (html,css,jquery).

I was asked to make a hybrid application for all the aforementioned platforms , that means implement push notification functionality and open an in-app web site which will be written (i guess..) in jQuery mobile.

My questions about it:

**1)** I read on the jquery mobile site , that the jquery mobile will run almost on every device and i saw the page with the OS and browsers that it supports. I found a simple site written in jquery mobile : `http://m.disneyworld.disney.go.com/` . I try to view this page on my devices. The iOS and Android view it perfectly but my `WP7 nokia lumnia800` and my `BB OS 5` devices cant load the page. So where is the compatibility that i read about?! From the page i read that these should be supported..

**2)** Do i use something like `codiqa` to build the look of my pages? In the `codiqa` page i cant extract the code unless i pay for a plan. However in the jquery mobile web page , i have a window with the basic `codiqa` panel , that allows me to do stuff and view the code. So do i use this one or not? I guess this is all about how the app really "looks". Then i have to script every component in jquery right? Do you guys use an "editor" like this ?

**3)** In the application i am building , when i load my html page , the user attaches to the URL a `device id` , cause i have a server that is responsible for subscriptions , registrations etc. So when i connect to my html is smth like that: `www.myURL.com#device_id`  **BUT** i read on the jquery mobile web page that i cant use the **#** anymore , as this is used to point the `pages` inside the `html`. So how can i work with that now?

**4)** In the end of the day , do i have to take care about all the different screens that the devices have? Or with jquery mobile everything is taken care of?

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: You should not refer to Mickey when it comes to developping...

Comment: @roasted i did not understand the mickey joke :( explain plz!

Comment: http://m.disneyworld.disney.go.com/

Comment: Platforms that supports jQM, http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't have a way to test the Disney site you reference on
   either a WP7 or BB5 device but it is entirely possible that if that
   site isn't rendering on those devices that is the result of markup
   or script beyond jQuery Mobile. I would suggest you code some simple
   test designs for your own site and see how those render on you WP7
   and BB5 devices. Also, how will you be developing the native portion
   of your hybrid app for all these platforms? That seems to be a much
   more significant issues than jQuery Mobile.
2. codiqa is a prototyping tool I don't know of many people that are
   using that tool to build production web sites. There may be people
   out there that do but most people I know code jQuery Mobile markup
   by hand or as part of a larger server side scripting technology. I
   use Visual Studio and asp.net mvc.
3. You are correct that you cannot use hash tags within jQuery Mobile
   but you can use standard query string parameters such as
   `m.myuser.com?deviceid=123`. Your approach will largely be dictated
   by your page implementation. Are you building based on a single page
   or multiple page template.
4. jQuery Mobile doesn't produce the ultimate, native looking web sites
   that you may hope for  but it does a great job of producing
   consistent looking sites that will render across a wide range of
   devices. You may have to tweak your site based on some gross
   categories of screen sizes or phones vs tables but no, if you build
   your site correctly, you shouldn't have to worry about every
   permutation of screen size.

Comment: thank you very very much for your great answer! 1) I didnt understand what did u mean with "Also, how will you be developing the native portion of your hybrid app for all these platforms?" What i did was wrote native code for all these platforms that implement push(that i need) and simply open a webView where the jquery page will be displayed. 3)"Are you building based on a single page or multiple page template."If i understand well here you are asking me , if i will write code for many pages in the same .html file or in different? If is in different i guess i can use the # ?

Comment: I saw that in jquery mobile the # is used to have multiple pages in the same .html file. So is used to navigate to every page. However if i dont have multiple pages in the same .html file , can i use it as i wanted? Also is there a special reason to keep many pages in the same file? Is it by any means faster? Cause if is a 30page site would be almost crazy to write all that code to the same file right? But from the other side all the tutorials i read , dictate using the # for having all the pages in the same .html. Whats your opinion on that?